# The TypeConverter for "Thickness" does not support converting from a string

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I am using following code for silverlight xaml file.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DBServer.Selenium.Silvernium.ReferenceApplication.SilverlightFixture"    
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="640" 
             d:DesignHeight="480">
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="frameContent" Source="/MainPage.xaml" Margin="0,0,0,0"/> // "Margin" on this line throws error
</UserControl>
```

But when i try to build it throws following error

```
The TypeConverter for "Thickness" does not support converting from a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and it didn't throw any error,are you sure its in the xaml and not the xaml.cs file that runs the code that's giving that error,because Thickness is how you define the margin in the running code like this

```
mainborder.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
```